# CSS: How to select last couple divs with same name?

Tags: css

Below I have some code. I can't change it, it has to be this way. 
With CSS I want to select the last 5 divs with class form-input-label-block
How can I get that done?

..............................................................................

```
<fieldset>
<div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Spouse" value="Spouse"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Spouse">Spouse</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Mother" value="Mother"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Mother">Mother</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Father" value="Father"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Father">Father</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Child" value="Child"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Child">Child</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Sister" value="Sister"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Sister">Sister</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Brother" value="Brother"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Brother">Brother</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Grandparent" value="Grandparent"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Grandparent">Grandparent</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Friend" value="Friend"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Friend">Friend</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Self" value="Self"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Self">Self</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Aunt" value="Aunt"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Aunt">Aunt</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Uncle" value="Uncle"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Uncle">Uncle</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Cousin" value="Cousin"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Cousin">Cousin</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Partner" value="Partner"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Partner">Partner</label>
</div>
</div><div class="radio-button-container">
<input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Other" value="Other"/>
<div class="form-input-label-block">
<label for="river_relationship_radio_Other">Other</label>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I think you cannot do that with CSS. You can do that with Javascript though, and add some other class if needed.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov The solutions are purely CSS based, and at the point of your comment, they were already here.

Comment: @connexo, it breaks if there is only 5 elements, which you mentioned yourself, and can be seen in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/740naar3/). As will every answer built with pure css, I believe, which is why I said what I did.

Comment: Why did you choose to select the worse answer? You had already selected the superior answer. What changed your mind?

Comment: .radio-button-container:nth-child(n + 10) {   background: red; }  that did not work, I tested it and it did nothing, I went to the next answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child()`

```css
.radio-button-container:nth-child(n + 10) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Spouse" value="Spouse" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Spouse">Spouse</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Mother" value="Mother" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Mother">Mother</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Father" value="Father" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Father">Father</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Child" value="Child" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Child">Child</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Sister" value="Sister" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Sister">Sister</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Brother" value="Brother" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Brother">Brother</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Grandparent" value="Grandparent" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Grandparent">Grandparent</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Friend" value="Friend" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Friend">Friend</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Self" value="Self" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Self">Self</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Aunt" value="Aunt" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Aunt">Aunt</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Uncle" value="Uncle" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Uncle">Uncle</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Cousin" value="Cousin" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Cousin">Cousin</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Partner" value="Partner" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Partner">Partner</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Other" value="Other" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Other">Other</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

or `:nth-child` with the general sibling selector `~`

```css
.radio-button-container:nth-child(9) ~ .radio-button-container {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Spouse" value="Spouse" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Spouse">Spouse</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Mother" value="Mother" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Mother">Mother</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Father" value="Father" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Father">Father</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Child" value="Child" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Child">Child</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Sister" value="Sister" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Sister">Sister</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Brother" value="Brother" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Brother">Brother</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Grandparent" value="Grandparent" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Grandparent">Grandparent</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Friend" value="Friend" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Friend">Friend</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Self" value="Self" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Self">Self</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Aunt" value="Aunt" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Aunt">Aunt</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Uncle" value="Uncle" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Uncle">Uncle</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Cousin" value="Cousin" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Cousin">Cousin</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Partner" value="Partner" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Partner">Partner</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Other" value="Other" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Other">Other</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: .radio-button-container:nth-child(9) ~ .radio-button-container {
      background: red;
   }   This worked, thanks

Comment: @aaandy awesome! be sure to choose which answer you think is the best solution to the problem.

Comment: Obviously this is the inferior approach since it will fail as soon as the number of radio boxes changes. It is better to begin counting from the end (which my answer does).

Comment: Even if they assume it won't change, there is no reason to use `:nth-child` over `:nth-last-child` here. On top of that, OP required to apply styles to `.form-input-label-block`, not `.radio-button-container`.

Comment: @connexo ok... what's your point? It's a solution and it solves the problem in the post.

Comment: My point is that for absolutely no reason you're suggesting a clearly inferior solution.

Comment: @connexo You seem to have been around for a while. There are obviously better and worse answers to all questions on stack overflow. That's what the voting and solution acceptance features are for. If someone offers a better solution, awesome. If not, that's fine, too, as long as it solves the problem. I don't see the point in either telling me or wanting to argue about it. Do you have a point? Or are you just sharing your opinion?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Why would it not be appropriate to call an inferior approach by the name? Obviously a solution that only works for a given number of elements lacks flexibility - and it doesn't even gain anything like simplicity to make up for this lack of flexibility. Also, as I pointed out, it ignores a requirement stated by OP.

Comment: @connexo I didn't say it was inappropriate. I'm asking why you're telling me. I don't see the point, unless you're just sharing your opinion, in which case I won't respond. I'm not arguing that my solution is better. I answered, that's it. Do you want me to do something, or are you just leaving your opinion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147103/discussion-between-connexo-and-michael-coker).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this CSS `<SomeTag/SomeClass>:nth-last-child(<Last n>)`
[CSS last n Child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.asp)

Comment: This does not select all of the last 5 children. It only selects the `nth` child, counting from the last child.

Comment: Sorry I assume you have knowledge basic CSS, you can refer to a class instead with tags, with that CSS also @VictorC.

Comment: Excuse me? I did not mention the selector at all. I am talking about your usage of `nth-last-child`, which is incorrect because it will only select the `nth` child from the end and not all children up to the `nth` child. Check who has the basic knowledge here.

Comment: While this is not a complete answer, it does point the direction to solve the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Update: This should work for an unknown number of radio boxes. (not tested for less than 5 radio boxes though).

```css
.radio-button-container:nth-last-child(6)~.radio-button-container .form-input-label-block {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Spouse" value="Spouse" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Spouse">Spouse</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Mother" value="Mother" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Mother">Mother</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Father" value="Father" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Father">Father</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Child" value="Child" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Child">Child</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Sister" value="Sister" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Sister">Sister</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Brother" value="Brother" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Brother">Brother</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Grandparent" value="Grandparent" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Grandparent">Grandparent</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Friend" value="Friend" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Friend">Friend</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Self" value="Self" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Self">Self</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Aunt" value="Aunt" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Aunt">Aunt</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Uncle" value="Uncle" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Uncle">Uncle</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Cousin" value="Cousin" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Cousin">Cousin</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Partner" value="Partner" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Partner">Partner</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-button-container">
    <input type="radio" name="river_relationship_radio" id="river_relationship_radio_Other" value="Other" />
    <div class="form-input-label-block">
      <label for="river_relationship_radio_Other">Other</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```